# Whats wrong with this Parcelable object passing?

Tags: android, parcelable

I have successfully passed arraylist of objects by using parcelable. But when i am trying to pass a object from one activity to another its not working.

In first Activity (ShowActivity), i have a gridView and for onclick i want to send a object to another activity and show the result of 1 one object's value :

**ShowActivity ::**

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
 {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,int position, long id) 
 {
   aStudent = students.get(position);
  Toast.makeText(ShowActivity.this, String.valueOf(aStudent.getstudentdID()), 2000).show();

  /*Intent myIntent = new Intent(ShowActivity.this,ViewStudentInfoActivity.class);
       myIntent.putExtra("studentObj", aStudent);
   //myIntent.putExtra("studentObj",   aStudent.getstudentName());
  startActivity(myIntent);*/

  Bundle b = new Bundle();
  b.putParcelable("studentObj", aStudent);
  Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(ShowActivity.this,ViewStudentInfoActivity.class);
  startActivity(myIntent2.putExtras(b));
  }
});
```

**And in onCreate() of ViewStudentInfoActivity ::**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewstudent_info);

    getPassedVal();
}


private void getPassedVal()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    /* if(intent!=null)
    {
    Student  aaStudent = (Student) intent.getParcelableExtra("studentObj");
    Log.d("vv", aaStudent.getstudentName());
    } */

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b != null) {
        Student  aaStudent = (Student)(b.getParcelable("studentObj"));
        String str = aaStudent.getstudentName().toString();
    }
}
```

Though the toast is showing the result, which means the object is ok. but cant retrive it from the second activity? Its weird. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: did you change the key?

Comment: @Raghunandan , thanks. Yes i have edited it and its working fine now. But still its working only when i use bundle. Not working when i am using intent only, which is as a comment in the code. Even i tried to pass just one value, which is not also working!!

Comment: if you want use commented code you need change `Intent intent = new Intent();` to `Intent intent = getIntent();`

Comment: @shayan pourvatan, thanks for the answer. Really a silly mistake!!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these lines:

```
b.putParcelable("studentObj", aStudent);
Student  aaStudent = (Student)(b.getParcelable("aStudent"));
```

You use different keys. "studentObj" vs "aStudent".

Answer (score 0):

try use following code:

```
 b.putExtra("studentObj", aStudent);  // instead of b.putParcelable
```

and for getting that:

```
 Student  aaStudent = b.getParcelable("studentObj");
```

if this not helped you please post `Student` class